# Define getter on a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, attributes, getter-setter

I know you cannot call `Object.defineProperty` on a string but I was wondering if there is a workarround to define getters on a string?

In other words, I'm looking for a workarround to be able to do something like this:

```
Object.defineProperty("Some string", "prop", {
    get: () => {
        return "Some other string";
    }
});
```

Maybe it's possible using symbol `toPrimitive`?

**Note:**
I know you can do `"Some string".prop = "something"` but that's not what I want, It's not the same as a getter

Comment: At best, this would be a hack. What do you need that for? Most likely there's a preferable alternative to this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a getter onto `String.prototype`, but that's your only option.  String values are primitives; only objects can have properties.  If you want a getter on a string, it must also appear on all strings.  (Your getter could choose to do nothing if `this != "some value"`, but that will of course apply to all strings that are `"some value"`, not some particular string you've created.)

Note also that `"Some string".prop = "something"` will throw when executed in strict mode code, which also includes class bodies, modules, and code explicitly marked as strict using `"use strict";` at the start of the overall script or an enclosing function.

Answer (score 3):

> JavaScript distinguishes between [String objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) and primitive string
>   values.

So you probably can define your string as a String object and...

```js
var s_obj = new String('one');

Object.defineProperty(s_obj, 'prop', {get: () => 'another'});

console.log(s_obj + ' : ' + s_obj.prop)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah but this would make `typeof s_obj` return `"object"` instead of `"string"`

Comment: Yes, because s_obj is object in fact. But you can always get the primitive. Easily.